# How to plot multiple lines in ggplot2 with years on x and frequecy on y

Tags: r, graph, stat

I have a data frame that looks like this

```
    TYPE              YEAR        
    ARSON             2008
    THEFT             2009  
    ARSON             2010
    ASSAULT           2008
```

The data continue's with more types and the years are between 2008-2012. I am trying to create a ggplot2 graph that has the the years on the x, the count of the type on the y and muliple lines representing each type.

I've tried melting with multiple variables and couldn't figure it out

Comment: Try creating one of [these](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that we can help you troubleshoot your code.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use melt. Use table() or one of the many other ways to count frequencies.

```
library(ggplot2)
yourData <- data.frame(TYPE = c('ARSON', 'THEFT', 'ARSON', 'ASSAULT'),
                       YEAR = c('2008', '2009', '2010', '2008'))
plotData <- as.data.frame(table(yourData))
ggplot(plotData, aes(YEAR, Freq, group = TYPE, color = TYPE)) +
    geom_line()
```